# Using SNMP to Find a Switch Port Number from a MAC Address

Tags: snmp, management, mac-address

I am following this guide http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/simple-network-management-protocol-snmp/44800-mactoport44800.html but it is not working for me. I have set this up on one network already and works fine using netgear switches. I am trying to set it up on a separate network of switches but i am getting no results. the command `snmpwalk -c public -v1 netgearpt03 .1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1` is returning nothing. On the switch that does work returns

```
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.17.4.3.1.1.20.254.181.217.110.102 = Hex-STRING: 14 FE B5 D9 6E 66 
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.17.4.3.1.1.20.254.181.217.110.138 = Hex-STRING: 14 FE B5 D9 6E 8A 
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.17.4.3.1.1.24.3.115.42.20.204 = Hex-STRING: 18 03 73 2A 14 CC 
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.17.4.3.1.1.24.3.115.45.252.24 = Hex-STRING: 18 03 73 2D FC 18 
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.17.4.3.1.1.24.3.115.45.252.125 = Hex-STRING: 18 03 73 2D FC 7D 
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.17.4.3.1.1.24.3.115.45.253.23 = Hex-STRING: 18 03 73 2D FD 17 
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.17.4.3.1.1.24.3.115.45.253.99 = Hex-STRING: 18 03 73 2D FD 63 
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.17.4.3.1.1.24.3.115.45.254.105 = Hex-STRING: 18 03 73 2D FE 69 
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.17.4.3.1.1.24.3.115.45.255.139 = Hex-STRING: 18 03 73 2D FF 8B
```

the none working netgear switch models are GS752TXS. is there any option to turn on dynamic cam tables?

the working netgear switch models are GSM7328S